# Live agent Prechat page is not populating Contact details on Case record in IE browser

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, liveagent

I am using Prechat page to create Case record when salesforce user accepts the Chat.
Its working fine in Chrome, but in IE it is not populating Contact details, it is not even getting logged in user ID. If I hard code user ContactID its working fine. Live Chat button is on Community VF page, I am trying to get community user logged in contact ID.
Can anyone please help me with this?

```
<form method='post' id='prechatForm'>

<!-- Hidden fields used to set additional custom details -->
      <input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:caseorigin' value='Chat'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:caseContactId' value='{!$User.ContactId}'/> <!-- if I hardcode this its populating values-->

        <input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:caseRecordType' value='{!$Label.Case_Recordtype_Commercial_Lines_Service}'/>

        <input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:ContactId' value='{!$User.ContactId}'/>   
        <input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:contactFirstName' value='{!$User.FirstName}'/>  
        <input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:contactEmail' value='{!$User.Email}'/>   
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Contact" value="FirstName,contactFirstName;LastName,contactLastName;Email,contactEmail;" />    
        <!-- Try to find the Contact by email (exact match) -->
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Email,true;FirstName,true;" />
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Email,true;FirstName,true;" /> 

       <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Case" value="LiveChatCategory__c,CaseCategory;LiveChatSubCategory__c,CaseSubCategory;Origin,caseorigin;ContactId,caseContactId;RecordTypeId,caseRecordType;"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Case" value="LiveChatCategory__c,true;LiveChatSubCategory__c,true;Origin,true;ContactId,true;RecordTypeId,true;" />
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Case" value="Origin,true;ContactId,true;RecordTypeId,true;" />    -->


        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Case" value="Case" />
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Case" value="true" />
<br></br>
<center><input type='submit' value='submit' id='prechat_submit'/></center>

<script type='text/javascript'>
 window.onload = function(){
    var button = document.getElementById('prechat_submit');
    button.form.submit();
}
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: Knowing the version of IE that is displaying this issue is important. Most versions of IE are no longer supported by Salesforce (and I believe they explicitly recommend _not_ using IE even for the "supported" versions).

Comment: @DerekF Thanks for your response, most of the users are using IE for some reason. So we need to fix this issue to use in IE. we are using Version 11.1087.16299.0

Comment: @Learner111 : Did you find a resolution to this issue ?